Is ''grace someone with you presence'' always humorous?
I have seen that many dictionaries say this expression is humorous. If that's true, what other alternatives exist that can be used in a formal setting such as a business meeting or at a meeting in which politicians participate.

I'd like to thank our business partners for being here and gracing us
with their presence at this meeting.


The president thanked the president of China/Canada/Peru,etc. for
gracing him with his presence

Is the expression too humorous to be used in contexts like the ones above? If so, can you please suggest alternatives that work better in formal settings?
Thank you in advance:-)

(Assuming that American usage is the same as British), the main meaning of the expression is literal; that an important person has honoured the assembled company by attending the function. It is sometimes used sarcastically, for example when someone arrives late.

Thank you. And can it also be used humorously when let's say someone never attends meetings but surprisingly the person shows up at a scheduled meeting?

Yes. The level of sarcasm would depend on to what extent the speaker thought that the person ought to attend meetings regularly.

Note that the OP asks if it's humorous and the answer talks about sarcasm. Humour and sarccasm are not identical. Personally I don't read the expression as funny. It would be interesting to see what others say.

Thank you for the other two comments.

@PeterKirkpatrick - Some online definitions refer to humour, some to sarcasm.  It seems to me that the humour in this case is bound to be a bit satirical.

To express it with clear honor and nothing else, use honor/honour per @KateBunting. People can honor us, but it's mostly royalty/clergy/God who grace us.

"I'd like to thank the president for visiting" or "I'd like to thank the president for taking time out of their busy schedule to be with us here today" are less likely to be ironic. It does depend how formal and long-winded you want to be. It might be better to thank them for something more specific (their visit, giving their thoughts, etc), rather than their presence which suggests they're just sat there doing nothing. But this is getting onto speechwriting which is more suited for Writing SE or maybe Interpersonal Relations.

Sarcasm depends on tone of voice. Not grammar or writing.

In my experience, this expression is almost always used sarcastically. It can be a harsh and rude criticism of someone arriving late, implying they think they're too important to arrive on time. Among friends, it might be meant good-naturedly, like many other rude things that are acceptable with friends.
The phrase is extremely formal, and might be used seriously if the person being addressed is nobility or a prominent religious figure like the Pope or the Dalai Lama. It might also be used seriously if the guest is extremely prominent in their field (Paul McCartney, Stephen Hawking, etc), but even then I think it's a little hyperbolic.
That said, "it is my pleasure" or more formally "it is my honor" should cover almost any situation.
For a business meeting, perhaps:

We are pleased / it is our pleasure to welcome our business partners to this meeting
we thank our partners for taking time out of their busy schedules to join us today / for coming all the way out to join us today

If the event is more formal than that, like a wedding or a diplomatic function, you could say:

it is our honor to host the president of Peru this evening
we are honored to welcome the president of Peru

I would mention that Americans culturally tend to use less formal language than many other places, and my experience is very reflective of that.
